# Play sound after clicking on imageview(array)

Tags: java, android

In XML file located 7 Imageview, example:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/imageview1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

In class: PageFragment extends Fragment i created array

```
 MediaPlayer[] mediaPlayers= new MediaPlayer[7];
```

initialized elements

```
  mediaPlayers[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.england);
        mediaPlayers[1]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.german);
        mediaPlayers[2]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.ukraina);
        mediaPlayers[3]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.russian);
        mediaPlayers[4]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.belarus);
        mediaPlayers[5]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.litva);
        mediaPlayers[6]= MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.japan);
```

**I want to play sound after click imageview**

```
switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.imageView1:
play mediaPlayers[0]
```

and i want: If I click on imagevie2 is playing a mediaPlayers[1] sound

Comment: Did you try `mediaPlayers[0].play();`?

Comment: Yes, but if I click on mediaPlayers[1].play();
the sound plays but mediaPlayers[0].play(); continues to play the sound

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code so that when you play a new sound you stop the one that is playing.
Also check the [MediaPlayer Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: please,help! I do not understand how to implement it